# Where are locale formats defined?

Tags: c, linux, internationalization, locale

For simplicity, let's only talk about Debian Linux.

I read the man page for [locale(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html), but it only talks about how to use locales.

I'm wondering where is the file that defines what formats the locale `es_ES.utf8` will use. For example, I want to see where `%c` is defined as `%Y %m %d` or where `%A` is defined as `Lunes` for `es_ES.utf8`.

I was poking around in `/usr/lib/locale`, but didn't find my answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `locale(1)` man page:

> **FILES**
>
> ```
> /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
> ```
>
> Usual default locale archive location.
>
> ```
> /usr/share/i18n/locales
> ```
>
> Usual default path for locale definition files.

Comment: Oh! I did find `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`, but it's a binary file. `/usr/share/i18n/locales` is what I'm looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to set-up all things is running the command: `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root.

You can find your default locales in the file: `/etc/locale.gen`

For a list of valid supported locales look at: `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`

If you want to set a locale, uncomment the locale line in `/etc/locale.gen` then run the command: `$ sudo locale-gen`

I am running Debian Jessie.